# Pair consecutive elements in a pd.cut-list to new histogram label-list?

Tags: python, list, label, cut

I want to set the labels of a binned histogram automatically based on the cut-intervals. The data-bins are created by applying pd.cut() on a dataframe. The list of the pd.cut is specified manually (see cut list), but I want the histogram labels to be set automatically based on the cut-list.
How do I convert the cut-list to a label list using code?

```
#cut list
cut = [0,20,40,60,80,100]

#desired label list
label = ['[0-20]', ']20-40]', ']40-60]', ']60-80]', ']80-100]']

#to be used for:
pd_cut = pd.cut(df, cut, labels=label, include_lowest=True).astype(str)
```

Comment: Why is the `[40-60]` label skipped?

Comment: It's a typo, my mistake. ;) I'll edit it, don't know why it happened. Thanks for reposting your answer, somehow it got deleted, that's why I reposted the part I tried already. It works beautifully!

Comment: I deleted it thinking I was wrong, but then I thought about it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to go through the pairs, and keep updating the list `label`:

```
cut = [0,20,40,60,80,100]

label = []

for i, p in enumerate(zip(cut, cut[1:])):
  ob = '[' if i == 0 else ']'
  label.append('{}{}-{}]'.format(ob, *p))

print(label)
```

Output:

```
['[0-20]', ']20-40]', ']40-60]', ']60-80]', ']80-100]']
```

Besides `zip`, `enumerate`, and the slicing, you can use a classic for loop with `range` and `len`:

```
for i in range(len(cut) - 1):
  ob = '[' if i == 0 else ']'
  label.append('{}{}-{}]'.format(ob, cut[i], cut[i + 1]))
```